# How to make eclipse aware of OSGI bundles within a maven repository (local &| remote)

Tags: java, maven-2, osgi, bundle

I have a project which is build through maven. Each module is built as an osgi bundle.

Within Eclipse the modules have also the plugin nature. Some modules require external dependencies (log4j, apache commons, ...), which are also available as plugins from a maven repository (for instance the spring enterprise repository, which is also an OBR).

Maven itself has no problem to resolve those dependencies, but how can I convince Eclipse to retrieve and resolve those bundles **as plugins** using a maven repository (I don't want to make for each of those a wrapper plugin)?

Is there a "Maven Provisioner" which could be installed in eclipse?

Comment: Are you using already a Maven plugin for Eclipse?

Comment: I have the same problem. The Maven plugin for Eclipse does not help here. The Eclipse PDE does not play nice with bundle dependencies managed by Maven, it insists on dependencies being in the workspace (as projects) or in the "target platform".

Comment: exactly! I think I will change the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't find anything, so I convinced my colleague to write an eclipse plugin which does exactly this. It is a provisioner which analyzes a m2 repository and pulls in the found osgi plugins from there. It is a alpha version, but you may try it and we are happy to get a response. Just write to info [at] inavare [dot] net

You find the update site here http://repo.openscada.org/eclipse/

Comment: The link is broken right now, which is kind of a pity. Do you know whether this has been implemented by someone else?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're not using a Maven plugin for Eclipse, if that's true you should try the one from [Sonatype](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) which in my opinion is the best. It resolves your dependencies, is really stable and has some nice features like the dependency graph tool.

Comment: I use the m2eclipse plugin, but it doesn't solve this problem. The maven build itself is fine, also the dependencies get resolved, but the validation for the MANIFEST.MF fails because of missing plugins (for instance log4j [I use the osgi bundle of springs OBR]). (I let the MANIFEST.MF create by the felix bundle plugin). So log4 is in the (local) repository, but not in any way resolved by Eclipse. I just want to have a way to point Eclipse to a local or remote maven repository, and let it resolve plugins automatically. (And no, I don't see buckminster in its current incarnation as an option)